# Is reactDOM.render() really needed?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a question.
I've been developing React components in the company I work for and never really used the `reactDOM.render()` function. 
(EXCEPT INSIDE INDEX.JS:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why is it needed elsewhere?
in order to render to the following component?

```
import React from 'react';

class Compo extends React.component {
render() {
  return <div />
}

export default Compo;
```

The way it is done is only via `<Compo />` in some other component render function, so I really cannot understand why `reactDOM.render()` is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: How is the parent component rendered from your application?

Comment: To mount your app to the DOM...?

Comment: Your question is why React team creates `reactDOM.render()`, right?

Comment: To use an analogy, this question is equivalent to asking why you need to turn on a computer first before using applications on it.

Comment: *I've been developing react components and never used reactDOM.render() function* - did you never create React app yourself? Because you won't be able to render an app to DOM without it.

Comment: Your app probably has reactdom.render() in it and you don't realize it.

Comment: what I meant is this: I do realize in each Index.js there should be a reactDOM.render(<App />, ) .... What I meant in my question is BESIDE INDEX.JS

Comment: > Why is it needed elsewhere?
It's not. You only need it in your entry point and nowhere else.

Comment: I see it everywhere. for example in the book I currently reading by react experts. at the end of every component there is a reactDOM.render()

Comment: Those are probably standalone examples—you need it once for every app. The book probably uses it so each example can be run on its own.

Comment: Got it. Thank you (: I did not realize this.

Comment: Another usage is that, if you want to render a react component without using it in any react application, with reactDOM.render you can use this function to render a react component.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have not find that..You better search for

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

in your main index.js or app.js. I think without having this render method it is not possible to make virtual dom.

Answer (score 3):

Well the basis behind

```
 ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

is that `ReactDom.render` compares the element and its children and updates only what is required

For example, if your element is like the following:

```
const element = <div>
                 <h1>
                  "sometext getting updated"
                 </h1>
                <div>
```

when your application creates a new element and passes it to `ReactDom.render()` it updates only the text field and as long has you have a single page application `ReactDom.render()` should be on the `index.js` as a single entry point.

Answer (score 1):

React Components contains the logic and the content to be displayed.

But it is with react-dom package methods, we can render the content into the DOM.

```
ReactDom.render(element,container[,callback]);
ReactDom.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here ReactDom.render function loads the element `<App/>` into the DOM in **root container.**